# ACPI event daemon

Tags: acpi

16.04 server...What is "ACPI event daemon" and why do I need it?  Can I turn it off somehow?  I am seeing lots of these:

```
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: automatic crash report generation...
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security apport[28990]:  * Stopping automatic crash report generation: apport
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security apport[28990]:    ...done.
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: automatic crash report generation.
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 16 06:05:03 signal-security systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security systemd[1]: Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security apport[29403]:  * Starting automatic crash report generation: apport
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security apport[29403]:    ...done.
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security systemd[1]: Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
Nov 16 06:05:04 signal-security systemd[1]: Reloading.
```

Comment: The ACPI Daemon is the daemon (disconnected process) that deals with ACPI events.  The Ubuntu page describes it nicely: acpid - Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/acpid.8.html  It can be used to deal with configuration and power events on your computer.